# norm on an exponential matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

Let $Q$ is a matrix with every element $0<q_{i,j}<1$ and each row sum of $Q$ being 1. Let $I$ be an identity matrix. Then, it is clear that $\|Q-I \|_{\infty} \le \|Q \|_{\infty} + \|I \|_{\infty} = 2$. Now I would like to find an upper bound on the norm $\|\exp(Q-I)\|_{\infty}$, where $\exp(\cdot)$ is defined as
$$ \exp(X) = I+X+\frac{X^2}{2!}+\frac{X^3}{3!}+...  $$

My initial idea is as follows:

$$ \|\exp(Q-I)\|_{\infty} \le \exp(\|Q-I\|_{\infty}) \le \exp(2)   $$

However, having tested this bound using some numerical values of $Q$, I find this bound a bit loose. I notice that, for the numerical values that I tested, the bound $\|\exp(Q-I)\|_{\infty} \le 2$ holds, but I do want to know how to mathematically prove it.

Ang suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the norm the induced $\infty$-norm rather than the induced $1$-norm? $\|Q\|_1+\|I\|_1$ can be arbitrarily close to $n+1$, which is greater than $2$ when $n$ is large. Consider a $Q$ whose first column is almost a vector of ones.

Comment: @user1551, Oh. You're right, Its $\infty$-norm.

Comment: Wait. If the norm is the induced $\infty$-norm (the absolute row sum norm), then $\|\exp(Q-I)\|_\infty$ is always equal to $1$, since $\exp(Q-I)$ is a row stochastic matrix. Perhaps you do want an upper bound of $\|\exp(Q-I)\|_1$, but you have mistakenly assumed that $\|Q\|_1=1$ in your argument?